# What are the .Net extensibility points of AD FS 3.0 (Windows 2012 R2 server role)

Tags: active-directory, adfs3.0

After having skimmed the documentation I can find on ADFS 3.0 I have found these two extensibility points:

- Custom Attribute Store
- AuthenticationAdapter

The way I understand it, the attribute store is injected into the pipeline after authentication and before claims are returned - and it can only introduce new claims - or change existing ones.

The other takes control of the whole pipeline and can finely grained control authentication and also the claims returned. It can be used to completely replace the backend store (f.ex AD) with a custom store both for authentication and claims returned once authenticated.

Is my understanding correct? Are there other extensibility points?

Hope you guys can help me clear my confusion, best wishes.